# Awesomium alert() handling and missing charset

Tags: c++, dialog, messagebox, awesomium

I'm working with Awesomium, but today I faced into multiple problems. The page what I've trying to show contains `alert()` functions and Yes/No message boxes, but it looks Awesomium can't handle them. I tried to use the `View` and `Dialog` listeners, but they aren't working. Is there an event which gets called when the page shows a message box? My second question is about the character set. The dropdown list on my site contains special (á, é, ü, ű, ö, ő) characters and the WebString can't handle them. It just shows a messed up characters.

Is there any solutions for these problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character set issue was my fault, it works properly by using unicode functions and I solved the `alert()` handling by using the `SetCustomMethod()` function with `OnMethodCall()`